# What custom dimension values should be used when creating GA4 dimension for Microsoft Clarity?

Tags: ms-clarity

#### MY QUESTION

What should I select when creating the custom GA4 dimension to integrate Google Analytics with Clarity?

#### MORE INFO

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/ga4-integration#step-2-1) says to remember the **Event Parameter Name** (*so I know the scope = event*) but *it* does not discuss the other variables that are required fields.

```
 1. ☒ Scope = Event
 2. ☐ User Property/Parameter?
```

#### WHAT I TRIED

Based on some [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/config#page_title) I first tried using *this* to pick up the dom title.

```
User Property/Parameter = page.title
```

*This* is picking up data from GA, however, when I tested this prior to production use, the data looked different and showed user traffic rather than number of events.

#### CONCLUSION

Can we get more information around how Clarity and GA work together, specifically the GA4 component?